# Angular 9 + erro ao passar variável na função direto do html

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angular, typescript

Galera, tenho uma dúvida sobre um erro que eu não entendo o porque. Tenho uma função que eu executo mediante a um clique, essa função tem que passar um único valor e está passando(testado via `console.log`). Função abaixo:

```
  removeL(form) {
    form = { idAcesso: form };
    console.log(form); // Testado e retornando tudo certo // idAcesso: "4"
    this.passosService.postRemoveL(form).subscribe(
      data => {
        if (!data.erro) {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      });
  }

  postRemoveL(form) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:80/admecp/admegp/getLC.php?xp0d1s6to=' + this.token;
    return this.http.post<any>(url, JSON.stringify(form))
      .pipe(map(dados => {
        return dados.invalid? this.authService.gout() : dados;
      }));
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(form)); // "idAcesso":"4"
```

O problema é que ele não retorna o valor esperado, se eu coloco o número 4 manualmente, ele retorna certo `this.passosService.postRemoveL('4')`.

Se eu coloco manualmente o número 4 numa variável e passo a variável, ele retorna corretamente também.
`form = { idAcesso: '4'};`

código HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="mr-2 text-danger" (click)="removeL(item.id)">
  <i class="fas fa-minus-circle fa-xs"></i>
</a>
```

E advinha, se eu coloco manualmente o número 4 no HTML, ele funciona!!! `(click)="removeL(4)"` .

Por favor, alguém sabe o problema? Eu já testei o back com o postman e phpmyadmin, então sei que o problema dificilmente é nele, fora que este backend é mais pra testar, não sou o resposável por esta parte, mas na dúvida, vou postar o código também.

```
  if($method === 'POST'){
    $body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $text = postaDadosUsers ($_GET['xp0d1s6to'], json_decode($body, true));
    echo $text;
    exit;
  }

  function postaDadosUsers($tk, $dados){
    $id = $dados['idAcesso'];
    $link = connect ();
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "call adm_remvl_stu('$tk','$id')")) {
        mysqli_close($link);
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            if ($row[0] == 'fr'){
                return json_encode($resp = array('invalid' => $row[0]));
            }
            return json_encode($resp = array('ok' => $row[0]));
        }
    }
  }
```

Ele não retorna erro. O código da requisição é 200, mas falta a resposta, além de não atualizar o BD.

Com o postman, tudo funciona, testando na aplicação mas inserindo os valores de forma manual, também funciona.

E aí? Alguma luz? Grato desde já!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera, RESOLVIDO!
Não sei o que era, só que eu testei no xampp funcionou. Eu reiniciei todas as aplicações e o próprio S.O. e aí funcionou também no WAMP, acredito ser algum bug ou falha na instalação de meu sistema. Só pode ser isso!